# Oracle's Unusual Behaviour: Either database not opened or connected to an idle instance on startup

Tags: oracle

I have been getting this issue multiple times whenever I am trying to connect to oracle db.

> Connected to an idle instance error

This was because the database din start correctly

> Database not started error even though connection has been made

This was because the database failed to shutdown.

Although, I was able to resolve this via startup command to mount the db again on connecting to an idle instance but why this unusual behaviour on switching off the oracle service after all the tasks have been performed as OracleServiceXE consumes a lot of Ram memory as well as disk.

Is there any way I could stabilize the connection each time the service gets closed and started because I run eclipse with oracle and I have only a 4gb ram so even if i start these services seperately there is 100% of disk as well as ram utilization.

Comment: Are the "not starting correctly" or "failing to shutdown" events perhaps accompanied by some error messages or diagnostic log entries which might help us understand what is unusual about them?

Comment: Nope they arent these events dont have any logs but i think this is because of large amount of internal memory consumption by the oracle services

Comment: I know its not related to programming but this behaviour doesnt allow me to work on 2 applications eclipse with oracle pl/sql simultaneously

Comment: So there is nothing in the alert log?  That seems unlikely.  If Oracle doesn't have enough memory to start, that should be written to the alert log.  If you believe the problem is memory, what have you done to decrease the memory Oracle is configured to use?

Comment: Yes, there isnt any log on the console as such but I am pretty sure its memory issue as I see the oracleservicexe process utilizing almost 100 % of the disk/ram usage several times